# tput does not try /dev/tty (?)

Tags: command-line

In Ubuntu 23.10, `echo -e "lines\ncols" | tput -S >/tmp/xx 2>&1` always writes "24\n80" to the file *regardless* of the terminal size.

The man page for `tput` says it successively tests stderr, stdout, stdin and ultimately **"/dev/tty"**, but it does not seem to actually try /dev/tty with the above command, and so produces a fallback of 24x80.

Can anyone point out the problem?

(the reason I'm redirecting both stdout & stderr is that some versions of BSD write error messages to stderr and I want my script to be silent even if run without a terminal -- in which case the default 24x80 is correct).

Comment: Same results in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ESM. Perhaps that is normal. Perhaps instead you should get GNOME terminal width / height?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You [need](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/87c2c84cbd2332d6d94b12a1dcaf12ad1a51a938/progs/tty_settings.c#L79) to add ["init" or "reset"](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/87c2c84cbd2332d6d94b12a1dcaf12ad1a51a938/progs/tput.c#L373C30-L373C37):

```bash
echo -e "lines\ncols" | tput init -S >/tmp/xx 2>&1
```

The `man tput` clearly puts that under the "init command":

> init   If  the  terminal  database  is present and an entry for the user’s terminal exists (see -Ttype above), the following will occur:
>
> (1)  first, tput retrieves the current terminal mode settings for your terminal.  It  does  this by successively testing
>
> •   the standard error,
>
> •   standard output,
>
> •   standard input and
>
> •   ultimately “/dev/tty”

#### Before

```
$ cat /tmp/xx
24
80
```

#### After

```
$ cat /tmp/xx
70
113
```

#### Alternative solution

As you said in a comment, you don't want to send the initialization sequence. In that case, you can just split that into two commands:

```
{ tput lines; tput cols; } >/tmp/xx 2>&1
```

Comment: Hmm.  So there is really no way to use tput to silently get the terminal size and not show an error if there is no terminal, AND without possibly wrecking the user's screen by sending the initialization string given in terminfo?

As noted in the original post, tput prints error messages to STDERR on bsd-ish platforms, so STDERR must be redirected to avoid undesired output when the script is run without a terminal e.g. from cron.   STDIN must be redirected to send in the capability string, and STDOUT must be redirected also to capture the answer.

Comment: @jimav I added an alternative solution that uses two commands instead of STDIN

Comment: Brilliant! I had forgotten that a capname could be passed as an argument. That (namely: `{ tput lines; tput cols; } >/tmp/xx 2>/dev/null`) is the the only answer I've seen which covers all the requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The stated method always returns 24 x 80:

```
$ echo -e "lines\ncols" | tput -S >/tmp/xx 2>&1
$ cat /tmp/xx
24
80
```

To find the true height / width you can use this method:

```
$ stty size
30 92
```

Answer (score 2):

For `tput` to be able to find columns/lines for the current terminal screen, at least one of the three standard streams STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR needs to be a tty (not a pipe/file) ... meaning:

```
echo -e "lines\ncols" | tput -S >/tmp/xx 2>&1
```

... has STDIN (at file descriptor `0`) as a pipe, STDOUT (at file descriptor `1`) as a file and STDERR (at file descriptor `2`) redirected as a file descriptor to STDOUT ... So, none are actually a tty.

So, either free one of the three like:

```
$ echo -e "lines\ncols" | tput -S >file; cat file
38
154
```

... where STDERR is a tty ... or:

```
$ tput -S >file 2>&1; cat file
lines
cols
38
154
```

... where STDIN is a tty ... or:

```
$ echo -e "lines\ncols" | tput -S 2>&1
38
154
```

... where STDOUT is a tty.

or, alternatively, tell `tput` to test `/dev/tty` with one of its special commands namely the ones described in [@DanielT's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1503889/968501).